# Computing the probability for a section of a joint distribution

Tags: math, probability, gaussian

Considering I have a continuous joint distribution of two independent normal random variables (let's assume the independent vars are on the X and Z axis, and the dependent - the joint probability - is on the Y axis), and I have a line anywhere on the XZ plane, how would I compute the probability of a point falling on one side or the other of that line?

Comment: How is this question programming-related?

Comment: Well, this has many applications in software for statistical analysis. I just didn't ask for code samples related to the solution because for me (and, probably, for most developers) they aren't necessary - if I got the concept I am able to turn it into code; also this is a language-independent problem. But code samples would be appreciated, from anyone willing to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First move everything so that the two normal distributions (the X and the Z) are centered on zero; now the joint ditribution will be a hill centered on the origin.

Now scale one of the axes so that the two distributions have the same variance (or "width"). Now the joint probability should be a rotationally symmetric hill.

Now all that matters is how close the line comes to the origin. Rotate about the origin (this will leave the joint probability unchanged) until the line is parallel to one of the axes, say Z. Now you're asking for the probability that a random point will have X greater or less than the X-value of the line. That's determined by one of the scaled ditribution functions (they're the same), and can be calculated by means of the error function.

I can write out the math if that would be useful.

EDIT: I'll try to write out the last step. Pardon my crude ascii, I don't have access to a good math tablet.

Suppose we've scaled and centered the distributions so that sigmaX = sigmaZ = 1, and rotated everything:

```
joint probability: P(x, z) = 1/(2 pi) exp(-(x^2 + z^2)/2)

line: x = c
```

Now to find the probability that a random point will be on a narrow "vertical" strip between some x and x+dx:

```
P(x)dx = Int[z=-Inf, z=+Inf]{dz P(x, z)}
       = 1/sqrt(2 pi) exp(-x^2/2) 1/sqrt(2 pi) Int[z=-Inf, z=+Inf]{dz exp(-z^2/2)}
       = 1/sqrt(2 pi) exp(-x^2/2)
```

But that's the same as (either) one of the two normal distributions. So the probability that a random point will be, say, to the left of the line is

```
P(c>x) = Int[-Inf, c]{dx 1/sqrt(2 pi) exp(-x^2/2)}
       = 1/2 (1 - Erf(c/sqrt(2)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I can follow your rationale, there's just one detail I didn't understand well. After the rotation & etc, you mean the integral for one of the sections of the 3D space would be the same as that for one of the sections of a 2D space taken from any of the two distributions? In other words, could I calculate the distance of the nearest point in the line from the origin and use it as the limit to integrate any of the functions, and that would give me the right result?

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could post the formulae for just this last step. Empirically it seemed to me that in order to "flatten" one of the dimensions you'd need to combine the two functions, because I supposed the corresponding curve would be steeper.

Comment: I believe you've interpreted the consequence of Beta's answer correctly in your first comment; due to symmetry considerations, the translated and scaled joint distribution is preserved by rotation, as is the shortest distance from the line to the origin.  Furthermore, any 2-D cross-section of the translated and scaled joint distribution will itself be a single-variable normal distribution.  So, yes, if you set the limits as described, this works.  

Of course, remove the word "normal" from your question, and all bets are off. :-)

Comment: In answer to the question, yes, you can calculate the distance from line to origin and use that as the integration limit. I just used rotation to make it clear (I hope) why this works.

Comment: Thanks. I asked because in my specific case this would make the implementation more time-efficient, since I already had the distance previously calculated for another use.

Comment: Just be sure you calculate the distance AFTER the scaling.